# Is is possible to get the required value from grid view on RowDataBound when user selects row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to get the `DeptID` from the selected Row i am binding the gridview as follows

```
private void PopulateGridView()
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblEmp", myConnection);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ad.Fill(ds);
    dynamicGrid.DataSource = ds;
    dynamicGrid.DataBind();

}
```

For applying colour to selected row i write as follows

```
protected void dynamicGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))
        {

            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:ChangeRowColor('" + e.Row.ClientID + "')");

            // e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location='Default9.aspx?id=" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "'");
            //e.Row.Attributes["onClick"] = "location.href='Default8.aspx?id=" + DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "id") + "'";
        }
    }
```

Script i used is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        //variable that will store the id of the last clicked row
        var previousRow;

        function ChangeRowColor(row)
        {
            //If last clicked row and the current clicked row are same
            if (previousRow == row)
                return;//do nothing
            //If there is row clicked earlier
            else if (previousRow != null)
                document.getElementById(previousRow).style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";//change the color of the previous row back to white

            document.getElementById(row).style.backgroundColor = "#ffffda";//change the color of the current row to light yellow
            window.open("Default9.aspx");
            //assign the current row id to the previous row id for next row to be clicked
            previousRow = row;
        }
     </script>
```

Now i would like to get the `deptid` of particular row when user selects on a row can any one help me and also how can i pass that to the following line in the script i used

```
    **window.open("Default9.aspx");**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your `RowDataBound`

```
DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
    if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))
    {
        int iEmpID = Convert.ToInt32(drv["DeptID"]);
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:ChangeRowColor('" + e.Row.ClientID + "','" + iEmpID + "')");
    }
```

and javascript as per `Dev` said

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the ChangeColor parameter like follow :

```
function ChangeRowColor(row,rowid)
{
   ...
}
```

and on Server Side change the onclick javascript :

```
//Get the value of specified cell
string DeptID = e.Row.Cells[0].Text; //change the index...

e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:ChangeRowColor('" + e.Row.ClientID + "','"+ DeptID +"')");
```

Comment: I would like to get the particular ID i need with that what i worte i am not getting DeptID

Comment: you can get all the value you want by call e.Row.Cells[n].Text

Comment: When i select the grid view why mu debugger is not getting to that `RowDataBound` Event

Comment: I written like this is it correct `window.open("Default9.aspx?Id='"+rowID+"'");`

Comment: window.open("Default9.aspx?Id="+rowID);

Comment: RowDataBound  event occurs when a data row is bound to data in a GridView control. not when you select the grid... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx

Comment: Ok then how can i get the value of the selected row in which event should i write. I am getting ID null i wrote this in the same event `string deptID = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you already pass the `rowID` to your JavaScript function, so why not pass the`deptID`at the same time ? You can have as many parameters as you want on your `ChangeRowColor` function.

On the server side, you can get the `deptID` by doing this:

`int deptID = (int)e.Row["deptID"]; //or maybe use Convert.ToInt32()`

Cheers